# How do I read in a txt file as a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, txt

I have a txt file  that is of the following format (dictionary format):

```
{'EX1':'No Information Stored',
'EX2':'Foundation',
'EX3':'Foundation',
'EX4':'No Information Stored'}
```

Does anyone know how I would go about reading this into python to be able to use it like the dictionary that it is?

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

with open('file.txt', 'r') as w:
   data = w.read()
   data_as_dict = json.loads(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Text file with this structure are JSON, so you can use the *json* module.

```
import json

def load_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return data
```

This is a custom function that return the dictionary you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ast.literal_eval().
It can be used for conversion of other data types as well

```
    # importing the module
import ast
  
# reading the data from the file
with open('dictionary.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
        
# reconstructing the data as a dictionary
d = ast.literal_eval(data)
  
print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods for this,

**1. Method using `json.load()`:**

`.load()` use to get from directly form file

```
import json
  
with open('data.json') as f:
   json.load(f)
```

**2. Method using `json.loads()`:**

`.loads()` use to get from string. So we need to read the file first to get string.

```
import json
  
with open('data.json') as f:
   json.loads(f.read())
```